# Screen scraping paginated results with zombie / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, web-scraping, zombie.js

What is the best method for looping through and scraping a result set of unknown length when using zombie / node.js?

Here's my base code:

```
var zombie = require("zombie");
var browser = new zombie.Browser({ debug: true, runScripts: true });
browser.visit("http://www.example.com/", function(err, browser, status) {
    browser.fill("searchbox", "my search query").pressButton("Search", function(err, browser, status) {
            process(browser.html());
            browser.clickLink('Next', function(err, browser, status) {
                process(browser.html());
            });

    });
});
```

My process() function takes the html and parses the results our of it, but short of adding infinite nested browser.clickLink() calls, I'm just not sure how to loop through the paginated results when I don't know how many pages there are in total (there is no indication in the html, but a 'Next' link).

Thanks.

Comment: save all the links in an array until there is no 'Next' link?